# Запуск службы через консоль

Tags: c#, linux, monodevelop

Как средствами С# на Linux запустить консоль и выполнить в ней определённую команду (в моём случае это запуск/остановка/проверка статуса службы из /etc/systemd/system)?

Comment: Так же как и на винде, только запускаете процесс `/bin/bash` с параметрами `-c "команда"`

Comment: Конкретно для управления службами можно попробовать подключаться к системной d-bus через библиотеку [Tmds.DBus](https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.DBus). Вот описание api: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.systemd1.html

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Создаем процесс для выполнения команды systemctl
        Process process = new Process();

        // Устанавливаем имя исполняемого файла для выполнения команды
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "systemctl";

        // Устанавливаем аргументы команды для получения списка всех служб
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "list-units --all --no-pager";

        // Указываем, что вывод команды должен быть перенаправлен в поток StandardOutput
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        // Запускаем процесс
        process.Start();

        // Читаем вывод команды из потока StandardOutput
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        // Ожидаем завершения выполнения процесса
        process.WaitForExit();

        // Выводим полученный список служб
        Console.WriteLine(output);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, использовать `.net core` и метод `Process.Start()` из семейства `System.Diagnostics`.

Например:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
    public static class ShellHelper
    {
        public static string Bash(this string cmd)
        {
            var escapedArgs = cmd.Replace("\"", "\\\"");

            var process = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "/bin/bash",
                    Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\"",
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                }
            };
            process.Start();
            string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

[Источник примера](https://loune.net/2017/06/running-shell-bash-commands-in-net-core/)

Comment: А bash-то зачем?